# asp.net mvc ajax send two parameters

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Why TestData does not receive anything?

> POST http://localhost:46628/Home/TestData 500 (Internal Server Error)

index.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: sendata">send data</button>
<script>
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.sendata = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/TestData',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { json: 'json', date: 'date' },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public void TestData(string json,string date)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use parameter `data` like this:

```
data: { json: 'json', date: 'date' },
```

Even though you specified that your content type is `json`, jQuery uses [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to serialize your data, so instead of sending the json the data is sent like this:

```
json=json&date=date
```

Your server though expects json to be provided, so model binding fails.

Instead you should manually serialize the data to json before making AJAX call:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ json: 'json', date: 'date' }),
```

The rest of the code seems to be fine.

Comment: Alternatively, remove the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` option so it uses the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`